# How to forward jsp page into html iframe?

Tags: jsp

I am doing college project in java JSP, In my index.html page i used 2  and i want to open one jsp page from 1 iframe to 2 nd iframe. I already tried to use  but it not support the target attribut.
 Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="security" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1"/>
        <title><s:message code="login.title"/></title>
        <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body id="body">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="logo"> <!-- space for logo --> </div>
                <div class="title"> <s:message code="login.title"/> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <div class="main-container">
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="<c:url value="/logout" />"  class="login-buttons"  style="float: right;"> Logout</a>
                    <h3>Message : ${message}</h3>                                              
                    <h3>Username : ${username}</h3>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                    <div style="width:32%;height:600px;float:left!important;">
                        <iframe id="tokbox" src="${requestScope.contextPath}/tokbox" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%" style="float:left!important;border:1px solid #000;" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless">

                        </iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width:67%;height:600px;float:left!important;border:1px solid #000;">
                        <iframe id="openMRS" src="http://ec2-54-229-226-106.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/openmrs/index.htm" width="100%" height="100%"     style="float:left!important;" frameborder="0"  seamless="seamless">

                        </iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>

            <div class="footer"> Copyright &copy; 2013. All Rights Reserved.</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```